# Image zoom in/out not working properly on positioning the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following code for image zoom in/out. The issue is when I try to position image according to my need  i.e. I apply margin left to image or image container i.e. #view it effects image zoom (in/out) – upon image zooming image starts moving to the left (because of margin) as you can see in the fiddle link below. Removing margin left makes this again run fine.  I want to place it to my wish place without having effect on zoom. Please let me know if I am not clear.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/N7KGz/1/)

```
/*style.css*/

    #view {
        border: 1px solid #333333 ;
        overflow: hidden ;
        position: relative ;
        width: 400px ;
        /*giving margin left to move image to the center*/
        margin-left: 400px;
        }

        .imageZoomInOut {
        display: block ;
        left: 0px ;
        top: 0px ;
        }

        #zoom {
        background-imageZoomInOut: url( "./white_fade.png" ) ;
        border: 1px solid #000000 ;
        cursor: pointer ;
        display: none ;
        height: 200px ;
        position: absolute ;
        width: 200px ;
        z-index: 100 ;
        }
```

```
//********************   js   *******************

// When the WINDOW is ready, initialize. We are going with
    // the window load rather than the document so that we
    // know our imageZoomInOut will be ready as well (complete with
    // gettable dimentions).
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // First, let's get refernces to the elements we will
    // be using.
    var view = $( "#view" );
    var imageZoomInOut = $( ".imageZoomInOut" );

    // Create the ZOOM element - this will be added with
    // Javascript since it's more of an "effect".
    var zoom = $( "<a id='zoom'><span><br /></span></a>" );

    // Before we start messing with the scripts, let's
    // update the display to allow for the absolute
    // positioning of the imageZoomInOut and zoomer.

    // Set an explicit height / width on the view based
    // on the initial size of the imageZoomInOut.
    view.width( imageZoomInOut.width() );
    view.height( imageZoomInOut.height() );

    // Now that the view has an explicit width and height,
    // we can change the displays for positioning.
    imageZoomInOut.css( "position", "absolute" );

    // Set an exlicit height on the imageZoomInOut (to make sure
    // that some of the later calcualtions don't get
    // messed up - I saw some irradic caculated-height
    // behavior).
    imageZoomInOut.height( imageZoomInOut.height() );

    // Before we add the zoom square, we need it to match
    // the aspect ratio of the imageZoomInOut.
    zoom.width( Math.floor( imageZoomInOut.width() / 2 ) );
    zoom.height( Math.floor( imageZoomInOut.height() / 2 ) );

    // Now, add the zoom square to the view.
    view.append( zoom );


    // ---------------------------------------------- //
    // ---------------------------------------------- //


    // Now that we have our UI set up physically, we need
    // to bind the event handlers.

    // We want to show and hide the zoom only when the
    // user hovers over the view.
    view.hover(
    function( event ){
    // Show the soom.
    zoom.show();
    },
    function( event ){
    // Hide the zoom.
    zoom.hide();
    }
    );


    // As the user mouses over the view, we can get the
    // mouse coordinates in terms of the page; we need
    // to be able to translate those into VIEW-based
    // X and Y cooridates. As such, let's get the offset
    // of the view as our base 0x0 coordinate.
    //
    // NOTE: We are doing this here so that we do it once,
    // rather than every time the mouse moves.
    viewOffset = view.offset();

    // Get the jQuery-ed version of the window as we will
    // need to access it's scroll offsets every time the
    // mouse moves over the div.
    //
    // NOTE: This will change the change the refernce to
    // "window" for all of the code in this closure.
    var window = $( window );


    // As the user moves across the view, we want to move
    // the zoom square with them.
    view.mousemove(
    function( event ){
    // Get the window scroll top; the mouse
    // position is relative to the window, NOT
    // the document.
    var windowScrollTop = window.scrollTop();
    var windowScrollLeft = window.scrollLeft();

    // Translate the mouse X / Y into view-local
    // coordinates that can be used to position
    // the zoom box.
    setZoomPosition(
    Math.floor(
    event.clientX - viewOffset.left + windowScrollLeft
    ),
    Math.floor(
    event.clientY - viewOffset.top + windowScrollTop
    )
    );
    }
    );


    // I position the zoom box within the view based on
    // the given view-local mouse coordinates.
    var setZoomPosition = function( mouseLeft, mouseTop ){
    // Ideally, we want to keep the zoom box centered
    // on the mouse. As such, we want the given mouse
    // left and mouse top coordiantes to be in the
    // middle of the zoom box.
    var zoomLeft = (mouseLeft - (zoom.width() / 2));
    var zoomTop = (mouseTop - (zoom.height() / 2))

    // As we move the zoom box around, however, we
    // never want it to go out of bounds of the view.

    // Protect the top-left bounds.
    zoomLeft = Math.max( zoomLeft, 0 );
    zoomTop = Math.max( zoomTop, 0 );

    // Protect the bottom-right bounds. Because the
    // bottom and right need to take the dimensions
    // of the zoom box into account, be sure to use
    // the outer width to include the border.
    zoomLeft = Math.min(
    zoomLeft,
    (view.width() - zoom.outerWidth())
    );
    zoomTop = Math.min(
    zoomTop,
    (view.height() - zoom.outerHeight())
    );

    // Position the zoom box in the bounds of the
    // imageZoomInOut view box.
    zoom.css({
    left: (zoomLeft + "px"),
    top: (zoomTop + "px")
    });
    };


    // Now that we have the mouse movements being tracked
    // properly, we need to track the click on the zoom to
    // zoom in the imageZoomInOut on demand. To do that, however,
    // we need to start storing some information with the
    // imageZoomInOut so we can manipulate it as needed.
    imageZoomInOut.data({
    zoomFactor: (view.width() / zoom.width()),
    zoom: 1,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: imageZoomInOut.width(),
    height: imageZoomInOut.height(),
    originalWidth: imageZoomInOut.width(),
    originalHeight: imageZoomInOut.height()
    });


    // Now, let's attach the click event handler to the
    // zoom box.
    zoom.click(
    function( event ){
    // First, prevent the default since this is
    // not a navigational link.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Let's pass the position of the zoom box
    // off to the function that is responsible
    // for zooming the imageZoomInOut.
    zoomImage(
    zoom.position().left,
    zoom.position().top
    );
    }
    );


    // I take the zoom box coordinates and translate them
    // into an actual imageZoomInOut zoom based on the existing
    // zoom and offset of the imageZoomInOut.
    //
    // NOTE: We don't care about the dimensions of the
    // zoom box itself as those should have already been
    // properly translated into the zoom *factor*.
    var zoomImage = function( zoomLeft, zoomTop ){
    // Get a reference to the imageZoomInOut data object so we
    // don't need to keep retreiving it.
    var imageZoomInOutData = imageZoomInOut.data();

    // Check to see if we have reached the max zoom
    // or if the imageZoomInOut is currently animating.
    // If so, just return out.
    if (
    (imageZoomInOutData.zoom == 5) ||
    (imageZoomInOut.is( ":animated" ))
    ){

    // Zooming in beyond this is pointless (and
    // can cause the browser to mis-render the
    // imageZoomInOut).
    return;

    }

    // Scale the imageZoomInOut up based on the zoom factor.
    imageZoomInOutData.width =
    (imageZoomInOut.width() * imageZoomInOutData.zoomFactor);

    imageZoomInOutData.height =
    (imageZoomInOut.height() * imageZoomInOutData.zoomFactor);

    // Change the offset set data to re-position the
    // 0,0 coordinate back up in the top left.
    imageZoomInOutData.left =
    ((imageZoomInOutData.left - zoomLeft) * imageZoomInOutData.zoomFactor);

    imageZoomInOutData.top =
    ((imageZoomInOutData.top - zoomTop) * imageZoomInOutData.zoomFactor);

    // Increase the zoom.
    imageZoomInOutData.zoom++;

    // Animate the zoom.
    imageZoomInOut.animate(
    {
    width: imageZoomInOutData.width,
    height: imageZoomInOutData.height,
    left: imageZoomInOutData.left,
    top: imageZoomInOutData.top
    },
    500
    );
    };


    // I reset the imageZoomInOut zoom.
    var resetZoom = function(){
    // Get a reference to the imageZoomInOut data object so we
    // don't need to keep retreiving it.
    var imageZoomInOutData = imageZoomInOut.data();

    // Reset the imageZoomInOut data.
    imageZoomInOutData.zoom = 1;
    imageZoomInOutData.top = 0;
    imageZoomInOutData.left = 0;
    imageZoomInOutData.width = imageZoomInOutData.originalWidth;
    imageZoomInOutData.height = imageZoomInOutData.originalHeight;

    // Animate the zoom.
    imageZoomInOut.animate(
    {
    width: imageZoomInOutData.width,
    height: imageZoomInOutData.height,
    left: imageZoomInOutData.left,
    top: imageZoomInOutData.top
    },
    300
    );
    };

     $("button").click(function(){

         resetZoom();
         });
    // As a final step, to make sure that the imageZoomInOut can
    // be zoomed out, bind the mousedown to the document.
    $( document ).mousedown(
    function( event ){
    // Check to see if the view is in the event
    // bubble chain for the mouse down. If it is,
    // then this click was in the view or its
    // child elements.
    var closestView = $( event.target ).closest( "#view" );

    // Check to see if this mouse down was in the
    // imageZoomInOut view.
    if (!closestView.size()){

    // The view was not found in the chain.
    // This was clicked outside of the view.
    // Reset the imageZoomInOut zoom.
    resetZoom();

    }
    }
    );
    });
```

```
<!--- html --->

<div id="view">
        <img class="imageZoomInOut" height="600" width="400" src="http://imedia.tv.com.pk/tvb/galery_celebrities/medium/Fawad_afzal_khan_image_90.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: In which browser are you testing this? It runs fine on Latest Version of Chrome....

Comment: its Version 28.0.1500.52

Comment: on v28.0.1500.95m it is working fine, but i was able to replicate your issue on Mozilla, check my answer below which fixes the issue on Mozilla (so i guess on your version of Chrome too)

Comment: i have firefox 22.0 - i am facing same issue upon zooming, image starts moving to right not zooming the actual place - i think you are facing issue in understanding the issue let me explain again: by removing 'margin-left:400px' or 'left:400' zoom works 100% fine. (compare the output by adding the margin/left and removing the margin/left). thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the padding to

```
left: 400px;
```

Tell me if this works for you

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/N7KGz/3/)**

Comment: bro it didn't fixed still the same issue - zoom is not working properly

Comment: I'm sorry Aamir but i replicated your issue only on Mozilla and with the change that i provided you above, it got fixed for me... If i can't replicate it on Chrome i am afraid i can't help you further...

Comment: ok. zoom box is active only on 50% of the image not on complete image if you drag cursor to right corner of image the box didn't work you can't zoom at right middle or right of the image. no zoom on right. thanks for help.